# How can I make textbox accept either comma (",") or dot (".") as decimal separator while preserving Culture and Locale in WPF?

Tags: wpf, localization

In my WPF project, usability tests show that users can type either dot or comma as a decimal separator at numeric input textboxes.

In order to cleanup that, I created a converter that replaces commas with dots, or dots with commas, and it works, but only if the culture uses the separator that is being replaced.

This is the code that is inside my converter's `ConvertBack` method:

```
return System.Convert.ToDouble(((string)value).Replace(',', '.');
```

My eyes hurt when I look at this, because it is an evident hack, and it is causing lots of errors, for sometimes it's necessary to replace comma, and sometimes to replace dot. We are in the verge of implementing actual localization in our software, so I ask:

"What would be the proper way to do it, that is, allow the user to use either comma or dot, without spoiling all the neat localization infrastructure?"

Comment: I've struggled for years with this and the best, most user-friendly, method is to do nothing.  If the computer's Culture uses the "," then the user is already going to want to use the comma as the decimal separator.  The same holds true for the "."  Don't try to second-guess the user.  .NET knows which decimal separator to accept based on the Culture setting, and that is the same one, that by default, the user will be most comfortable with.  And for goodness sake, don't mess with the users Culture settings; down that road lies madness.

Comment: @Stewbob do you think I should at least block/validate while the user inputs, so that if he chooses the wrong separator the system warns him?

Comment: Yeah, I've done that before with success.  Basically just like you've shown in your answer.  Have received zero negative feedback from users doing it that way.

Answer (score 2):

After some research following the very wise suggestion from Stewbob, I decided to only allow the user to input the current culture decimal separator. For that, I listen to `PreviewTextInput` in code behind.

The effect is that the user can only type numbers, then the current decimal separator once, then more numbers. Other characters simply "don't respond". We think this is fair usability-wise.

```
    private void PreviewNumberInput(object sender,
                                    System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e) {

        string input = ((TextBox)sender).Text + e.Text;

        string pattern = "^[0-9]+[" +
                          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator +
                          "]?([0-9]+)?$";

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(input);
    }
```